# Is it possible to extract logic app as seen in the designer view?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, visio

I am trying to extract logic app as seen in the designer view but couldn't find any other option than to draw it myself on Visio. Did my research but couldn't find any way to do that. Is there any app/logic to extract logic app as seen in the designer view?

Comment: Nah, screenshots are you best friend for this I'd say unless you want to process the JSON and build something that way, that'd be a bit keen though.  What's the use case?

Comment: Designing a document, explaining about the working model to clients. I have 80 logic apps and screenshotting each of them will take a lot of effort and time.

Comment: I’d suggest writing your own logic to generate something in Visio would likely take longer though.

Comment: https://github.com/modery/PowerDocu ... might only work for PowerAutomate and not LogicApps but would be worth looking into.

Comment: @Skin Thanks for the link. I I'll work on making a tool to extract logic app as in designer tool whenever I have time. Had some ideas...

Answer (score 0):

- As mentioned by @Skin, there is no way to extract the designer view of logic app.
- Either you need to take screen shots or designing logic app designer in Visio by yourself.
- As of now the available options for extracting logic app is the arm template of logic app code.
- Exporting template of a resource can be find in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/export-template-portal#export-template-from-a-resource)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of times, set a Window orientation to vertical, zoomed out in the designer to fit the screen (full screen mode can help), then taken a screen shot.

Super clunky, but if it's for documentation no one will actually read, it works.